# Get before and after rows SQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT `PersonID`, `Title`.`Title`, `FirstName`, `LastName` 
FROM `Person` 
ORDER BY `cft` ASC, `FirstName` ASC
```

Now the problem is because the results are not numeric, Is there way to get the before and after rows if I set the `PersonID` to be say 1020?

Comment: I don't understand. Before, and after what rows do you need? And how many rows before it, and how many after it?

Comment: So you want all rows except those that personId equals 1020?

Comment: just 1 before, and 1 after, because of the order by the result set is not consecutive.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a condition for the next row (assuming there are no similar `FirstName` for each `cft`):

```
WHERE (`cft` = :cft AND FirstName > :firstname) OR (`cft` > :cft)
ORDER BY `cft` ASC, `FirstName` ASC
LIMIT 1
```

where `:cft` and `:firstname` are the correspondent values from the row with `PersonID = 1020`.

Condition for the previous row is pretty similar to the one I've shown and I'm sure you could get it yourself (treat it as a homework)

Comment: @Chud37: no, I mean - I don't give you a complete solution for you to have a chance to bring some effort yourself :-)

Comment: This is what I'm coming up with:
`SELECT `PersonID`, `Title`.`Title`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `cft` 
FROM `Person` 
LEFT JOIN `Title` ON `Person`.`Title` = `Title`.`id` 
WHERE ((`cft` = :cft AND FirstName > :firstname) 
OR (`cft` > :cft)) 
AND (`PersonID`='340')
ORDER BY `cft` ASC, `FirstName` ASC`

Comment: @Chud37: `:cft` is a placeholder and you need to substitute it with the actual value from the row you're keen of. So just select by another query the whole row with `PersonID='340'` and put the values there manually. Yes, the total solution will take 2 separate queries. And - specify integer values as is, without single quotes around. PS: "not working" is never helpful - you always have to provide a error message.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your persistance.  The only error messages I ever get with phpMyAdmin is 'check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near' and then part of the SQL statement, which never seems to help me so I didnt include it :S

Comment: @Chud37: "and then part of the SQL statement, which never seems to help me so I didnt include it" -- actually it's the part that is wrong syntactically )) Anyway - you need to replace `:cft` and `:firstname` placeholders with actual values manually and see if it works

Comment: `SELECT `PersonID`, `Title`.`Title`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `cft` 
FROM `Person` 
LEFT JOIN `Title` ON `Person`.`Title` = `Title`.`id` 
WHERE (`cft` = '1' AND `FirstName` > 'Ruth') 
OR (`cft` > '1')
ORDER BY `cft` ASC, `FirstName` ASC`

returns no rows and no errors either :(

Comment: `cft` is either 1 or 0 too, does that make a difference?

Comment: "returns no rows and no errors either" -- then there is no rows which fit condition `cft = '1' AND FirstName > 'Ruth'` - so, there is no next row after Ruth.

Comment: "cft is either 1 or 0 too, does that make a difference?" --- as I said, if the type of column is numeric - don't enclose the value in quotes. Just use `1`, not `'1'`